# Trying to position images and text on a page in a certain manner (examples included)

Tags: html, css

Having a bit of trouble adjusting a specific page's layout to look like the design I created prior, still getting to grips with positioning with CSS.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

And this is the layout I'm after

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square" src="Long_Term_Relationships.jpg">              
<h4>Forging Strong Long Term Relationships</h4>
<p>We focus on strong, long term relationships with our clients</p>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square" src="focus.jpg">    
<h4>Focus</h4>
<p>We focus on understanding our clients' long term strategies</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square" src="Team.jpg"> 
<h4>A Clear Sense of Team</h4>
<p>We work closely as a team, irrespective of our diverse work</p>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square" src="integrity.jpg">    
<h4>Intergrity</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square"  src="excellence.jpg">  
<h4>Excellence</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-square" src="delivery.jpg"> 
<h4>Delivery</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<hr>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.img-square {
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}

.core-value {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in your style may help you

```
.img-square {
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
}

.core-value {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that was incredibly simple haha, now its just a case of adding padding to space them out a little... Is it possible to make the photos look more square with CSS instead of rectangle? Or would I literally have to re-size them in PhotoShop?

Answer (score 0):

Include `float:left` e remove `display:block;` from `.img-square`

```
.img-square {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
}

.core-value {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```